# child class with extra arguments python class inheritance

Tags: python, apache-spark, inheritance, pyspark

I wrote a parent class:

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, spark_session=None):
        try:
            # Instantiate Spark Session
            self.spark = spark_session
            if not self.spark:
                self.spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000).appName("SparkTest") \
                    .getOrCreate()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Initialization of spark & logging couldn't be performed: {}".format(e))
```

Then the child class has an extra argument in its constructor which is path:

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, path, spark=None):
        self.spark = super().__init__(spark)
        self.path = path
```

Then when I write this:

```py
a = Child("path", None)
print(a.spak)
```

For:

```py
self.spark = spark_session
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'spark' None
```

Any idea how to fix this and make spark object instantiate as expected.

Regards

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback (maybe remove your name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.spark = super().__init__(spark)`

`__init__` is **not** a constructor. It **init**ializes the object's attributes and  returns `None`, not the object.

`self.spark` will be automatically initialized once you call `super().__init__`.

Note I also changed `Parent.__init__` a bit. In your code `self.spark` is not defined in case an exception is raised which will lead to other errors down the road.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, spark_session=None):
        self.spark = spark_session            
        try:  
            if not self.spark:
                self.spark = SparkSession.builder .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000).appName("SparkTest") \
                .getOrCreate()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Initialization of spark & logging couldn't be performed: {}".format(e))


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, path, spark=None):
        super().__init__(spark)
        self.path = path
```